# Date manipulation in React js

Tags: javascript

I am trying like this:

```
var db = new Date('2017-12-03T13:32:45.000Z');
console.log(db.getMonth());
```

to get the month from given date but it gives the previous month. 
Any suggestion...?

Comment: months are 0-based in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour, it's zero-based so January = 0, February = 1 etc. If you want the current month, you need:

```
let db = new Date('2017-12-03T13:32:45.000Z'); 
console.log(db.getMonth() + 1);
```

Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)